# How to get session value in Javascript but my javascript code is in the code behind in asp.net. I am trying to set the variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying  get the session value in javascript in my `asp.net` code behind.
But the syntax is wrong I don't know how to get the session value.
Here in my question i trying to set the value of sesindex variable which is a session value which i dont know how to set its totaly different

I tried to call javascript on page load normally its calling is fine. But when I am trying to set the variable value as session value its not calling alert box so their some where I put wrong but I don't know what it is.

Here is the code behind code:

```
str += "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
             //"alert('testing');" +
            "var sesindex = '<%=Session["indexval"]%>';" +
                "alert(sesindex);" +

                 "</script>";
```

I want to set `sesindex` value and show in alert  box. I am trying to set the value but its not working. It is working fine in html page. But its not working in code behind.

Comment: Are you tried `RegisterStartupScript`/`RegisterClientScriptBlock` already? How you're inject the script into ASPX page?

Comment: Yes. When i comment the below two lines code its show the alert box testing but its not working the sesindex varible set code. I dont know that is it right or wrong

Comment: well, the `["indexval"]` should have thrown an exception. This version will work on aspx side of things where `'<%=Session["indexval"]%>'` will be rendered to something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass session value from code behind to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815197/how-to-pass-session-value-from-code-behind-to-javascript)

Comment: No its different  from that question. Because their they directly pass session value which is normally doing in asp.net i.e. string str = session["set"].ToString(). Here i want to set a value in javascript and its not working as per your answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't really like this but you can try this to get value into the string.

```
var sesVal = Session[indexval];

str += "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
        $"var sesindex = '{sesVal==null?"":sesVal.ToString()}'" +
            "alert(sesindex);" +"</script>";
```

This will get you covered when the value is null. You can read about `$"{}"` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

Comment: var sesVal = Session["indexval"];    Its not a proper way to set  a value the cursor is not move after this line

Comment: Aha, sorry forgot to remove quotes around the variable name.

Comment: Thank u for your concern.  But still its not working the cursor is not move after this line

Comment: Javascript not throwing any error when we write in code behind. I checked by debugger its directly break after var sesval = session["indexval"].ToString() line. Its not showing alert box

Comment: In aspx page we directly assign var session = '<%=Session["indexval"]%>' its gives proper result but in code behind how set var session as a session value

Comment: In code behind, you have `Session` object oob. So you can pass key or index to get value from it like `Session ["UserName"]` or `Session[0]`. Things are stored as `Object` and will return `null` if there is no item for a given key or at index (Not sure, may actually throw `IndexOutOfBounds` exception for index). It seems, `indexval` is a variable in which you store the index like `indexval=1;`